# Can't create index on geometry object

Tags: python, mongodb, indexing, geojson

I've been trying to create an index on geometry object in my collection in order to use the mapbox map integrated in mongodb compass but i'm failing to get over the index creation phase. I have searched all over for a solution for this but I couldn't find anything helpful so far, if anyone can help me that would be great. I have included an example of the error it gives me.

```
[............. [ 0.4528048, 46.9900928 ], [ 0.4549714, 46.9893069 ], [ 0.4558275, 46.9889921 ] ] Edges 233 and 235 cross. Edge locations in degrees: [0.5085185, 47.0253468]-[0.5085648, 47.0253438] and [0.5085645, 47.0253438]-[0.5088490, 47.0254293]
```

Comment: Can you share an example of the implementation you tried?

Comment: @AndréTeixeira I have created it in mongo compass not by query , I clicked on the index part then create index then specified the geometry field and "2dsphere" as the index type then clicked on the create button